# OBJECT_DEFINITION for VIEW in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

As the Title says, is it able to query `object definition` of the view in Databricks using `SQL`, especially for Azure Databricks?

like when using SQL Server, I'm able to query the view definition using function `OBJECT_DEFINITION` or Stored Procedure `sp_helptext` to display the `SELECT statement` within `Views`.

I'm looking all over the internet, don't find one that explains about this. May be there isn't an option?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's maybe not very obvious, but you can use [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-create-table.html) SQL command for that - it works for both tables & views.  For example if I have view as following:

```sql
create view if not exists tacls.tbl1_view as
select * except(grp) from tacls.tbl1;
```

then I can get definition with

```sql
show create table tacls.tbl1_view
```

the definition will be in the `createtab_stmt` column:

[image]